# PyCharm remote interpreter (2019.1) + Matplotlib import error

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pycharm

Upon building a new conda environment with Python 3.6, PyQt5 (pyqt==5.6.0) was having issues initializing from PyCharm, version 2019.1.

After `ssh -Y` into the box, building plots from an iPython shell worked fine.

But importing `matplotlib` from PyCharm threw the following error:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/share/dir/python/conda-env-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-a0d2faabd9e9>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/home/user/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/share/dir/python/conda-env-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2609, in <module>
    install_repl_displayhook()
  File "/share/dir/python/conda-env-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 166, in install_repl_displayhook
    ip.enable_gui(ipython_gui_name)
  File "/home/user/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 130, in enable_gui
    return real_enable_gui(gui, app)
  File "/home/user/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/inputhook.py", line 536, in enable_gui
    return gui_hook(app)
  File "/home/user/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/inputhook.py", line 174, in enable_qt
    from pydev_ipython.qt_for_kernel import QT_API, QT_API_PYQT5
  File "/home/user/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/qt_for_kernel.py", line 115, in <module>
    QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg, QT_API = load_qt(api_opts)
  File "/home/user/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/qt_loaders.py", line 258, in load_qt
    if not can_import(api):
  File "/home/user/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/qt_loaders.py", line 146, in can_import
    if not has_binding(api):
  File "/home/user/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/qt_loaders.py", line 114, in has_binding
    imp.find_module('QtCore', mod.__path__)
  File "/share/dir/python/conda-env-py36/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 270, in find_module
    "not {}".format(type(path)))
RuntimeError: 'path' must be None or a list, not <class '_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'>
```

Following the stacktrace and looking into the relevant files leads me to believe it is something to do with conda installation or PyCharm recognition of the packages within the conda env.

Has anyone else experienced problems running PyQt5-based plotting with Matplotlib 2.2.2 from PyCharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing pyqt, I used conda. When running `conda install`, the PyQt package appeared to be linked, instead of copied into the environment. The link wasn't behaving as expected apparently.

I solved this by specifying `--copy`. See [conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html?highlight=install#Package%20Linking%20and%20Install-time%20Options) for details. Here's the full install command:

`conda install pyqt==5.6.0 --copy`

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was, that I installed pyqt5 via pip and pyqt was already installed via conda.
Run:

```
conda remove pyqt
conda install matplotlib
```